# How do I pass Token Storage as a param to an Event Listener in Symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, authentication, service, event-listener

I have successfully set up an Entity Event Listener in Symfony 3.4. I registered the service like this, in the Resources/config/services.yml of a separate bundle:

```
services:
    resource.listener:
        class: Company\ResourceManagementBundle\EventListener\Entity\ResourceUpdateListener
            arguments: ["@security.token_storage"]
            tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, method: preUpdate }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate, method: postUpdate }
```

I also added the necessary code in the Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\EntityListeners(
 *    {"Company\ResourceManagementBundle\EventListener\Entity\ResourceUpdateListener"}
 * )
 */
class Resource implements UserInterface
{
```

Then in my Event Listener, I created a constructor with Token Storage as the only parameter, type-hinted with the TokenStorageInterface. Here is my event Listener:

```
namespace Company\ResourceManagementBundle\EventListener\Entity;

use Company\ResourceManagementBundle\Service\UserNoteLogger;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\TokenStorageInterface;

class ResourceUpdateListener
{
    protected $fields;
    private $token_storage;

    function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $token_storage)
    {
        $this->token_storage = $token_storage;
    }

    public function preUpdate(Resource $resource, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        if ($entity instanceof Resource) {
            $changes = $args->getEntityChangeSet();
        }
        return $this->setFields($entity, $args);
    }
    public function postUpdate(Resource $resource, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $hasChanged = false;
        if ($entity instanceof Resource) {
            foreach ($this->fields as $field => $detail) {
                if($detail[0] == null) {
                    //continue;
                } else {
                    $hasChanged = true;
                }
            }
            if ($hasChanged == true) {

                $userNoteLog = new UserNoteLogger($args->getEntityManager(), $this->token_storage);
                $comment = "The resource, " . $resource->getFullName() . ", was changed by the user, " . $this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser()->getFullName();
                $userNoteLog->logNote($comment, $resource);
            }
        }
    }
    public function setFields($entity, LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $this->fields = array_diff_key(
            $eventArgs->getEntityChangeSet(),
            [ 'modified'=>0 ]
        );
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Company\ResourceManagementBundle\EventListener\Entity\ResourceUpdateListener::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenStorage\TokenStorageInterface, none given, called in /var/www/sites/sentient02/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/ContainerAwareEntityListenerResolver.php on line 83

This error does not go away, as long as the Token Storage parameter exists in the constructor.

If you look at the **EventListener** code above, I am trying to log information every time the Entity changes during the update, and this information needs to know the name of the logged in user.

Answer (score 2):

The service definition seems OK, but by default, the EntityListener annotation only support empty constructor.

See in the [Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners-class) :

> An Entity Listener could be any class, by default it should be a class
>   with a no-arg constructor.

A little clarification here :

- a **Doctrine Event Listener** is called for all entities (generally 
  require test like `$entity instanceof MyClass` before doing any action)
- a **Doctrine Entity Listener** are used for easy case, and are only called on one entity.

In your code, it seems that you write a common doctrine listener, but use it as an entity listener.

Furthermore, you already declare your service like a common doctrine event with the `doctrine.event_listener` tag (EntityListener must have the `doctrine.orm.entity_listener` tag.)

In short, if you just delete the `@ORM\EntityListeners` annotation, it should be ok.

Note that to get changes when update an entity, you can use the onFlush event. Here is an example with the very useful `unitOfWork` in order to get an array with all fields that will change in the scheduled updates.

```
  /**
   * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
   */
  public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
  {
      $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
      $unitOfWork = $entityManager->getUnitOfWork();

      // Get all updates scheduled entities in the unit of work.
      foreach ($unitOfWork->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {

          if ($entity instanceof Resource) {

              dump( $unitOfWork->getEntityChangeSet($entity) );
              // In this array, you'll have only fields and values that will be update.
              // TODO : your stuff.
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `autowire: true` in your `services.yml`:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.
```

Take a look at the docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html.